# Regex to find words EXCEPT when inside <a> </a>

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to replace some words with a html link tag, but I ONLY want to do this when the word is NOT found inside an existing link element.

So I'd like to replace FOO in this markup:

```
<p>Once upon a FOO there was a BAR</p>
```

But I do NOT want to replace FOO in this markup:

```
<p>Once upon a <a href="coolsite.net">FOO</a> there was a BAR</p>
```

I don't really understand how to solve this. I'm guessing something to do with look aheads and look behinds, but I don't really know where to start.

It's ok to run it server side to avoid Safaris limited support for look ahead/behinds.

Comment: Regular expressions are not powerful enough to understand HTML's syntax, which you'll need in the more interesting cases, like `<a href="x"><b>FOO</b></a>` (this is inside an existing link element) and `<a href=""></a>FOO<a href=""></a>` (this is not). You may have to use an HTML parser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348

Comment: Alternatively, if you are already in the browser, you may want to do this by walking the DOM, either directly or using a library like jQuery.